# Problems porting Tensorflow code to Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have been bashing my head against the wall for the past few days - and I simply cannot figure it out. 
Would some of you good people perhaps let me know what I am doing wrong?

I am trying to port code from https://github.com/simoninithomas/Deep_reinforcement_learning_Course/blob/master/Deep%20Q%20Learning/Doom/Deep%20Q%20learning%20with%20Doom.ipynb (written in Tensorflow) to Keras. Here is the original part of the code:

```
class DQNetwork:
    def __init__(self, state_size, action_size, learning_rate, name='DQNetwork'):
        self.state_size = state_size
        self.action_size = action_size
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate

        with tf.variable_scope(name):
            self.inputs_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, *state_size], name="inputs")
            self.actions_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 3], name="actions_")

            self.target_Q = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None], name="target")

            #First convnet: CNN => BatchNormalization => ELU; Input is 84x84x4
            self.conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs = self.inputs_,
                filters = 32, kernel_size = [8,8],strides = [4,4],padding = "VALID",
                kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer_conv2d(), name = "conv1")

            self.conv1_batchnorm = tf.layers.batch_normalization(self.conv1,training = True,
                epsilon = 1e-5,name = 'batch_norm1')

            self.conv1_out = tf.nn.elu(self.conv1_batchnorm, name="conv1_out")
            ## --> [20, 20, 32]


            #Second convnet: CNN => BatchNormalization => ELU
            self.conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs = self.conv1_out,
                filters = 64,kernel_size = [4,4],strides = [2,2],padding = "VALID",
                kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer_conv2d(),name = "conv2")

            self.conv2_batchnorm = tf.layers.batch_normalization(self.conv2,training = True,
                epsilon = 1e-5,name = 'batch_norm2')

            self.conv2_out = tf.nn.elu(self.conv2_batchnorm, name="conv2_out")
            ## --> [9, 9, 64]


            #Third convnet: CNN => BatchNormalization => ELU
            self.conv3 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs = self.conv2_out,
                filters = 128,kernel_size = [4,4],strides = [2,2],padding = "VALID",
                kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer_conv2d(),name = "conv3")

            self.conv3_batchnorm = tf.layers.batch_normalization(self.conv3,training = True,
                epsilon = 1e-5,name = 'batch_norm3')

            self.conv3_out = tf.nn.elu(self.conv3_batchnorm, name="conv3_out")
            ## --> [3, 3, 128]


            self.flatten = tf.layers.flatten(self.conv3_out)
            ## --> [1152]


            self.fc = tf.layers.dense(inputs = self.flatten,
                units = 512, activation = tf.nn.elu,
                kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(),name="fc1")


            self.output = tf.layers.dense(inputs = self.fc, kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(),
                units = 3, activation=None)


            # Q is our predicted Q value.
            self.Q = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(self.output, self.actions_), axis=1)


            # The loss is the difference between our predicted Q_values and the Q_target
            # Sum(Qtarget - Q)^2
            self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.target_Q - self.Q))

            self.optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(self.learning_rate).minimize(self.loss)

# farther below...

Qs_next_state = sess.run(DQNetwork.output, feed_dict = {DQNetwork.inputs_: next_states_mb})

# Set Q_target = r if the episode ends at s+1, otherwise set Q_target = r + gamma*maxQ(s', a')
for i in range(0, len(batch)):
    terminal = dones_mb[i]

    # If we are in a terminal state, only equals reward
    if terminal:
        target_Qs_batch.append(rewards_mb[i])
    else:
        target = rewards_mb[i] + gamma * np.max(Qs_next_state[i])
        target_Qs_batch.append(target)

targets_mb = np.array([each for each in target_Qs_batch])

loss, _ = sess.run([DQNetwork.loss, DQNetwork.optimizer],
                    feed_dict={DQNetwork.inputs_: states_mb,
                               DQNetwork.target_Q: targets_mb,
                               DQNetwork.actions_: actions_mb})
```

And here is my conversion:

```
class DQNetworkA:
    def __init__(self, state_size, action_size, learning_rate):
        self.state_size = state_size
        self.action_size = action_size
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate

        self.model = keras.models.Sequential()
        self.model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (8, 8), strides=(4, 4), padding = "VALID", input_shape=state_size))#, kernel_initializer='glorot_normal'))
        self.model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization(epsilon = 1e-5))
        self.model.add(keras.layers.Activation('elu'))

        self.model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (4, 4), strides=(2, 2), padding = "VALID"))#, kernel_initializer='glorot_normal'))
        self.model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization(epsilon = 1e-5))
        self.model.add(keras.layers.Activation('elu'))

        self.model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (4, 4), strides=(2, 2), padding = "VALID"))#, kernel_initializer='glorot_normal'))
        self.model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization(epsilon = 1e-5))
        self.model.add(keras.layers.Activation('elu'))

        self.model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
        self.model.add(keras.layers.Dense(512))
        self.model.add(keras.layers.Activation('elu'))

        self.model.add(keras.layers.Dense(action_size))

        self.model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=self.learning_rate))

        print(self.model.summary())

# farther below...

Qs = DQNetwork.predict(states_mb)
Qs_next_state = DQNetwork.predict(next_states_mb)

# Set Q_target = r if the episode ends at s+1, otherwise set Q_target = r + gamma*maxQ(s', a')
for i in range(0, len(batch)):
    terminal = dones_mb[i]
    t = np.copy(Qs[i])
    a = np.argmax(actions_mb[i])

    # If we are in a terminal state, only equals reward
    if terminal:
        t[a] = rewards_mb[i]
    else:
        t[a] = rewards_mb[i] + gamma * np.max(Qs_next_state[i])

    target_Qs_batch.append(t)
    dbg_target_Qs_batch.append(t[a])

targets_mb = np.array([each for each in target_Qs_batch])

loss = DQNetwork.train_on_batch(states_mb, targets_mb)
```

Everything else is the same. I have even tried to mess around with a custom loss function to minimize differences in the code – and it simply does not work! While the original code quickly converges my Keras doodlings simply does not seem to want to work!

Does anyone have a clue? Any hints or help would be highly appreciated...

*A little further explanation:*

This is a simple DQN playing Doom - so the after about 100 episodes (games), the model seems to be able to shoot the target without a problem every episode. Loss goes down, rewards per game go up - as one would expect... However, in the Keras model loss graph is flat, reward graph is flat - it almost seems not to be able to learn anything. (see the graphs linked below)

Here is how it works. In TF code, model outputs a tensor [a, b, c] where a, b and c give probability of each action the main character might take (ie: [left, right, shoot]). Model is then given reward for every action, so it is passed a target value (target_mb, f.ex. 10) along with which action this is for (one-hot encoded in actions_mb, ie [0,1,0] - if this is a target for moving right). Loss is then computed with a simple MSE over difference between target and predicted value of the model for the given action.

I have done two things:

1) I tried to use the standard "mse" loss as I have seen in other models of this type. To make the loss behave the same way, I pass the model its own input apart from target value. So if model predicts [3,4,5] and the target is 10 for [0,1,0] - we pass [3,10,5] as the truth to the model. This should be equivalent to the actions of the TF model. ie, difference between 10 and 4, squared and then mean over all differences from the batch.

2) When 1) did not work, I tried to make a custom loss function that basically attempts to mimick behaviour of the TF model as closely as possible. So if model predicts [3,4,5] and the target is 10 for [0,1,0] (as above) - we pass [0,10,0] as the truth to the model. Then the custom loss function through some finicky multiplication and division arrives at difference between 10 and 4 - squares it and takes mean of all squared errors as below:

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    isolated_truths = tf.reduce_sum(y_true, axis=1)
    isolated_predictions = tf.divide(tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(y_true, y_pred), axis=1), isolated_truths)
    delta = isolated_predictions - isolated_truths
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(delta))

# when training, this small modification is made to targets:
loss = DQN_Keras.train_on_batch(states_mb, targets_mb.reshape(len(targets_mb),1) * actions_mb)
```

And it still does not work (although you can see on the graphs that the loss seems to behave far more reasonably!).

Take a look at the graphs:

tf model: https://pasteboard.co/IN1b5MN.png

keras model with mse loss: https://pasteboard.co/IN1kH6P.png

keras model with custom loss: https://pasteboard.co/IN17ktg.png

*edit #2 - runnable code*

Original TF code - copy pasted from tutorial above, working:
=> https://pastebin.com/QLb7nWZi

My code with custom loss in full:
=> https://pastebin.com/3HiYg6t7

Comment: What do you mean by "it simply does not work"?

Comment: Well, the TF model seems to converge fine. This is a simple DQN playing Doom - so the after about 100 episodes (games), the model seems to be able to shoot the target without a problem every episode. Loss goes down, rewards per game go up - as one would expect... However, in the Keras model loss graph is flat, reward graph is flat - it almost seems not to be able to learn anything!

Comment: In the tensorflow code, there are three types of input, namely, states_mb, targets_mb, and actions_mb. But in your keras code, only states_mb is fed into the model as input. Any explanation?

Comment: Yes, this is due to the fact that the TF model uses a custom loss function. Model is passed target of a certain action, and it basically computes a MSE of the target predicted versus the one given. states_mb are the input to the model (image sequence from the game screen), targets_mb are the Q target value - and the action_mb is one-hot encoded action

Comment: It is a little difficult to explain, so I will post an explanation above in an edit :)

Comment: So you can ensure that the inputs for tensorflow model and keras model are same?

Comment: The inputs (states_mb) are completely the same yes, but the truths passed upon training are not - and as far as I can see cannot be. Please correct me if I a wrong, but Keras expects outputs of the model to be the same shape as truths, right?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I would like to know whether you train your tensorflow model with min-batch? I'm confused because of the brief code.

Comment: I see that you first `sess.run(DQNetwork.output)` and then `sess.run([DQNetwork.loss, DQNetwork.optimizer])`, do you execute these two operations with mini-batch or the whole dataset?

Comment: I have now updated my post with links to full code, it is actually rather brief - and most of it is the same apart from the TF/Keras parts :) They are only executed on the minibatch. `sess.run(DQNetwork.output)` is run to predict reward of the next state the game screen will be (next_states_mb) after the given action (actions_mb) is taken on current state (states_mb). This is all done to calculate discounted rate (part of Q-learning paradigm), meaning that the reward for the current action taken will include reward for the next state.

Comment: It seems tricky to implement the model in keras, sorry for not helping you.

Comment: I find two links, which I hope can give you a clue: [link](https://github.com/flyyufelix/VizDoom-Keras-RL), [link](https://github.com/itaicaspi/keras-dqn-doom).

Comment: Ah, ok, thank you for trying anyways :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have made work - by removing BatchNormalization layers. Now I am completely mystified... so does batch normalization work differently in Keras and Tensorflow? Or is the missing clue this mysterious "training=True" parameter in TF (not present in Keras)?

***PS.***
While digging into the issue, I also found this *very* useful article describing how to create advanced Keras models with several inputs like masks (like in the original TF code!):

https://becominghuman.ai/lets-build-an-atari-ai-part-1-dqn-df57e8ff3b26